# Разбиение 2-мерного пространства с прямоугольниками для нахождения соседей

Tags: алгоритм

Есть массив с непересекающимися прямоугольниками, расположенными на плоскости. Необходимо разделить пространство таким образом, чтобы можно было для любого прямоугольника найти соседние.

Посоветуйте на какие алгоритмы стоит обратить внимание?

Comment: Прямоугольники - осеориентированные или не обязательно?

Comment: Да, осеориентированные

Comment: Каков критерий для соседства? Расстояние? Прямая видимость? Принадлежность к кластеру?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Общее решение: диаграмма Вороного для исходных прямоугольников. Диаграмма Вороного даст вам разбиение пустого пространства между вашими прямоугольниками на регионы, которые будут обладать тем свойством, что граничащие регионы разбиения соответствуют соседним прямоугольникам.

Диаграмма Вороного решит эту задачу для произвольных многоугольников. В вашем случае можно ожидать каких-то оптимизаций за счет того, что ваши многоугольники - именно прямоугольники. Но это может быть, например, просто упрощенный процесс построения диаграммы.

Вот, например, диаграмма Вороного для случайного набора осеориентированных прямоугольников, построенная в метрике Чебышева

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Тот факт, что регион Вороного для прямоугольника 1 имеет общую границу с регионом Вороного для прямоугольника 2, говорит о том, что прямоугольники 1 и 2 являются соседями. Также соседями являются 1 и 5 за счет короткого участка общей границы между их регионами Вороного. А тот факт, что регион Вороного прямоугольника 4 не имеет общих границ с регионом Вороного прямоугольника 1, говорит о том, что соседями они не являются.

Обычно в таких задачах диаграмма Вороного позволяет вам сгенерировать набор *предварительных кандидатов* на соседство и сразу отсеять явных "не соседей". А далее вы уже можете выбрать нужных вам соседей в соответствии со своими, более тонкими критериями. В данном примере на картинке эти критерии могут, в частности, использоваться для принятия решения о том, считать ли соседями прямоугольники 1 и 5.